# Facebook Developer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to register my tumblr website with Facebook in accordance with this tutorial http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=62825. But when I enter my website like this, I get a validation error. Why is this not a valid domain name?

Note, I am using my own domain name with Tumblr

```
Validation failed.
Site Domain: http://www.blahblah.com/ is not a valid domain.
```

And I also got this error message when I tested a like button on the site

```
The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http://blahblah.com/post/6196969104/.
```

[image]

Comment: are you putting in leaftalk.com with http and www or just leaftalk.com?

Comment: @Fourth, I've tried it different ways. What's it supposed to be?

Comment: See my comment below in my answer. It is based on the working web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of things, you're redirecting `www.leaftalk.com` to `leaftalk.com`. The value for your site domain should be `leaftalk.com` (note, no trailing slash). The value for site URL should be `http://leaftalk.com/`

Comment: Thanks, I put an image in my OP. It has Site URL and Site Domain. Do you know what I would put in Site Domain?  I put www.leaftalk.com and it said not a valid domain, and I also put leaftalk.com/ and it wasn't valid

Answer (score 2):

Try just typing in the

```
blahblah.com
```

without http://
I remember I had similar problem like that before. Once it is connected, I think like button will work just fine.

Comment: Do you know what it means when it says Connect Base Domains?

Comment: Thanks, I put an image in my OP. It has Site URL and Site Domain. Do you know what I would put in Site Domain? I put www.leaftalk.com and it said not a valid domain, and I also put leaftalk.com/ and it wasn't valid

Comment: In Site URL I put `http://mydomain.com/` and in Site domain, I put `mydomain.com`